# error running make install with playerpro

Tags: c, makefile, cmake

I don't know where else to ask this, but I'm trying to build a relatively obscure music tracker program called playerpro, and I'm running into a `make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.` error when I run `make install`. I don't know how to fix this myself, since I'm pretty new to doing anything besides running the standard build commands, and I figured I'd come here for help

Do you have any suggestions?

I don't know what you'll need, but here's my makefile:

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.20

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all
.PHONY : default_target

# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:

#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : %,v

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : RCS/%

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : RCS/%,v

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : SCCS/s.%

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : s.%

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list

# Command-line flag to silence nested $(MAKE).
$(VERBOSE)MAKESILENT = -s

#Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:

# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:
.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = /usr/bin/cmake

# The command to remove a file.
RM = /usr/bin/cmake -E rm -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /home/autumn/PlayerPRO

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /home/autumn/PlayerPRO

#=============================================================================
# Targets provided globally by CMake.

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
    /usr/bin/cmake --regenerate-during-build -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache
.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake cache editor..."
    /usr/bin/ccmake -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : edit_cache

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache
.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/autumn/PlayerPRO/CMakeFiles /home/autumn/PlayerPRO//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/autumn/PlayerPRO/CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all

# The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

# The main clean target
clean/fast: clean
.PHONY : clean/fast

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

# clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named PlayerPROCore

# Build rule for target.
PlayerPROCore: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 PlayerPROCore
.PHONY : PlayerPROCore

# fast build rule for target.
PlayerPROCore/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f MADDriver.source/CMakeFiles/PlayerPROCore.dir/build.make MADDriver.source/CMakeFiles/PlayerPROCore.dir/build
.PHONY : PlayerPROCore/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named UMX

# Build rule for target.
UMX: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 UMX
.PHONY : UMX

# fast build rule for target.
UMX/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/UMX.dir/build.make MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/UMX.dir/build
.PHONY : UMX/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named OKTA

# Build rule for target.
OKTA: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 OKTA
.PHONY : OKTA

# fast build rule for target.
OKTA/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/OKTA.dir/build.make MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/OKTA.dir/build
.PHONY : OKTA/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named AMF

# Build rule for target.
AMF: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 AMF
.PHONY : AMF

# fast build rule for target.
AMF/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/AMF.dir/build.make MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/AMF.dir/build
.PHONY : AMF/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named MTM

# Build rule for target.
MTM: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 MTM
.PHONY : MTM

# fast build rule for target.
MTM/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/MTM.dir/build.make MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/MTM.dir/build
.PHONY : MTM/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named DMF

# Build rule for target.
DMF: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 DMF
.PHONY : DMF

# fast build rule for target.
DMF/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/DMF.dir/build.make MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/DMF.dir/build
.PHONY : DMF/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named IT

# Build rule for target.
IT: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 IT
.PHONY : IT

# fast build rule for target.
IT/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/IT.dir/build.make MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/IT.dir/build
.PHONY : IT/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named MADfg

# Build rule for target.
MADfg: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 MADfg
.PHONY : MADfg

# fast build rule for target.
MADfg/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/MADfg.dir/build.make MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/MADfg.dir/build
.PHONY : MADfg/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named XM

# Build rule for target.
XM: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 XM
.PHONY : XM

# fast build rule for target.
XM/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/XM.dir/build.make MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/XM.dir/build
.PHONY : XM/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named MADH

# Build rule for target.
MADH: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 MADH
.PHONY : MADH

# fast build rule for target.
MADH/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/MADH.dir/build.make MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/MADH.dir/build
.PHONY : MADH/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named 669

# Build rule for target.
669: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 669
.PHONY : 669

# fast build rule for target.
669/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/669.dir/build.make MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/669.dir/build
.PHONY : 669/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named S3M

# Build rule for target.
S3M: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 S3M
.PHONY : S3M

# fast build rule for target.
S3M/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/S3M.dir/build.make MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/S3M.dir/build
.PHONY : S3M/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named MOD

# Build rule for target.
MOD: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 MOD
.PHONY : MOD

# fast build rule for target.
MOD/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/MOD.dir/build.make MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/MOD.dir/build
.PHONY : MOD/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named MADI

# Build rule for target.
MADI: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 MADI
.PHONY : MADI

# fast build rule for target.
MADI/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/MADI.dir/build.make MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/MADI.dir/build
.PHONY : MADI/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named MED

# Build rule for target.
MED: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 MED
.PHONY : MED

# fast build rule for target.
MED/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/MED.dir/build.make MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/MED.dir/build
.PHONY : MED/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named ULT

# Build rule for target.
ULT: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 ULT
.PHONY : ULT

# fast build rule for target.
ULT/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/ULT.dir/build.make MADDriver.source/Import-Export/CMakeFiles/ULT.dir/build
.PHONY : ULT/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named PPPlay

# Build rule for target.
PPPlay: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 PPPlay
.PHONY : PPPlay

# fast build rule for target.
PPPlay/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f Examples/PPPlay/CMakeFiles/PPPlay.dir/build.make Examples/PPPlay/CMakeFiles/PPPlay.dir/build
.PHONY : PPPlay/fast

# Help Target
help:
    @echo "The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:"
    @echo "... all (the default if no target is provided)"
    @echo "... clean"
    @echo "... depend"
    @echo "... edit_cache"
    @echo "... rebuild_cache"
    @echo "... 669"
    @echo "... AMF"
    @echo "... DMF"
    @echo "... IT"
    @echo "... MADH"
    @echo "... MADI"
    @echo "... MADfg"
    @echo "... MED"
    @echo "... MOD"
    @echo "... MTM"
    @echo "... OKTA"
    @echo "... PPPlay"
    @echo "... PlayerPROCore"
    @echo "... S3M"
    @echo "... ULT"
    @echo "... UMX"
    @echo "... XM"
.PHONY : help



#=============================================================================
# Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

# Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
# No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
# because they might be regenerated.
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

Comment: Not every Makefile has an "install" target. This one apparently doesn't. So if the other targets, like "all", doesn't do what you want then you need to update the cmake with the desired targets or install it manually.

Comment: how do i install it manually?

Comment: "how do i install it manually?" - Copy files which has been built with `make` into the desired location. What do you want from us? The project you use doesn't define `install` target.

Comment: sorry, i was hoping someone would give me some tips on how to add an install target